# Pay with Stripe or Braintree in Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, paypal, stripe-payments, braintree

Is it possible to make payment with Braintree, PayPal, Stripe or something else in Meteor without using Node packages?

I have found multiple projects on GitHub, but they are all very complicated and use Node modules.

I would have thought it would be quite simple to implement payment in Meteor, but it seems some complex.

Answer (score 0):

There are a [number of Meteor packages](https://atmospherejs.com/universe/modules?q=stripe) for Stripe on AtmosphereJS [0] including a [Meteor-native implementation](https://atmospherejs.com/benjick/stripe-native).  I haven't really worked with Meteor much, so I can't really comment on them, but I'm sure one of them will work for what you're trying to do.

More generally, the Stripe API is quite comprehensive because Stripe can do a lot of things, but if you're just looking to [accept a customer's card](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) and [process a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/charges) that's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

To integrate with Braintree without using the Braintree Node module, you would have to make requests against the Braintree XML API, which is not publicly documented.

If you decide to use the Braintree node package here is an [example Meteor integration](https://github.com/NickTomlin/braintree-meteor-example) you could take a look at.